# docusign - USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT, User has already provided consent

Tags: javascript, node.js, docusignapi

I created a dummy account, through which I gave consent for main account APP.

I saved the UUID in the DB once authorized.

I created a JWT token using the APP integration key, UUID stored in the DB. Using following code

```
let apiClient = new Docusign.ApiClient();
apiClient.setOAuthBasePath(dsConfig.dsOauthServer.replace('https://', ''));  
const res = await apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
    integratorKey, 
    uuid, 
    "impersonation signature", 
    rsaKey.toString(), 
    3600
);
```

Using the main accounts accountId, I'm trying to create an envelope where I'm receiving this error about USER_DOES_NOT_BELON_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT.

```
let dsApiClient = new Docusign.ApiClient();
    dsApiClient.setBasePath(dsConfig.dsBaseUri);
    dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);

let envelopesApi = new Docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient)
  , results = null;

results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(dsConfig.accountId, {
    envelopeDefinition: envelope
});
```

Here -

```
dsConfig.dsOauthServer > 'https://account-d.docusign.com'
dsConfig.dsBaseUri > 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'
```

In the dummy account, I checked the consent is there in **Manage Profiles**/ **Connected Apps**.

This is all happening in sandbox developer accounts.

Please help

Comment: Are you 100% sure the dsConfig.accountId is the right account ID for your dummy account where you gave consent that was used to get the token?

Comment: dsConfig.accountId and the uuid must match the same account (not same value, but the userId for the user for this accopuntId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AccountId and userId are not the same. Note that account is a higher-level object and one account can have many users.
You must use the same account and user for that account.
Meaning your `dsConfig.accountId` value is the GUID for the account in which the `uuid` you used for the token is a member.

This error means that DocuSign didn't find the user for which you authenticated in the account ID you provided as part of the API call to create an envelope.

Comment: Yes that was the mistake I was doing. I considered accountId for the main account instead of the dummy account.